# Handling same context path for multiple micro service in zuul configuration

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

We are building platform on top of Spring netflix OSS to host multiple use-cases micro service api. One of the use case have 2 API (2 code base building 2 jars) they want it to be hosted on 2 different service Id but both are having same context url 
eg "/loan/card/v1/individual/"

AP11-> /credit_decision/payment_plan/

API2 -> /history_decision/payment_plan/

How should I configure the rout path so that any call coming via url

/loan/card/v1/individual/credit_decision/payment_plan/ should go to API1 and

/loan/card/v1/individual/history_decision/payment_plan/ should go to API2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define the routing like below. I have the strip-prefix to false in case you need it you can make it true. For more info here is the link to the [DOC](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_router_and_filter_zuul).

```
zuul:
  routes:
    API1: 
         path: /loan/card/v1/individual/credit_decision/**
         service-id: API1
         strip-prefix: false
    API2: 
         path: /loan/card/v1/individual/history_decision/**
         service-id: API2
         strip-prefix: false
```